# Добавление class или id для страниц категорий

Tags: php, opencart

Как правильно изменить:

```
<body class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
```

чтобы вместо стандартного:

```
<body class="product-category-57">
```

выводилось допустим:

```
<body class="product-category-57 page-category">
```

или

```
<body id ="page-category" class="product-category-57">
```

и выводилось это только для страниц категорий.

---

Пришлось сделать через jquery, но все равно интересно ваше мнение

Comment: какие в ос есть функции определения категории?

Answer (score 1):

**UPD:**

в `common/header.php` найдите строчку:

```
} else {
    $data['class'] = 'common-home';
}
```

И после неё допишите:

```
if($this->request->get['route'] == 'product/category') {
    $data['class'] .= ' page-category';
}
```

Comment: это будет выводиться на всех страницах

Comment: не посмотрел, что в body) Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если вариация предыдущего ответа не работает, то проверяйте `$class` и если он совпадает с `product-category`, то добавляйте нужные данные. К примеру:

```
$classlen = srtlen($class);
if($classlen > 16) { // 16 кол-во символов "product-category", вроде
$classname = substr($class, 16);
if($classname == 'product-category'){
$classtype = 'product-category';
}
} else {
$classtype = 'other';
}

if($classtype == 'product-category') {
<body class="<?=$class;?> page-category">
} else {
<body class="<?=$class;?>">
}
```

Ну или как-то более красиво сообразите)